# Is there a theoretical derivation of Kim's delayed choice quantum eraser?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, interference, quantum-optics, quantum-eraser

Is there a theoretical derivation of Kim's delayed choice quantum eraser?
The original paper only shows the experimental data.

Comment: Oh, my. The way you have worded this question seems tuned to trigger my favorite pet peeve, but I'll keep it short: data (good, reproduced data) trumps theory every time. Which is why physicists don't do "proofs" but rather "derivations" (if these initial conditions obtains and this fact is physically true then we should expect this other thing to follow). Please don't let the mathematical style of most physics instruction make you lose sight of that important distinctions.

Comment: If it's a theoretical exploration of how the experiment works and what it demonstrates that you want, did you look at [the original Scully and Drühl proposal](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.25.2208)?

Comment: @dmckee I'm pretty sure theory *beats* experimentation to the "results" most of the time. Relativity, Classical Mechanics, perhaps not QM but certainly more advanced theories like the Standard Model prediction of the Higgs Boson...

Comment: @zach You may have taken the wrong meaning from my comment. That isn't about a race or contest between theory and experiment. It's about the philosophy of the discipline. Beautiful and correct math is all well and good, but it has to describe the world to be physics. So asking for a "proof" of an observed effect get the causality backwards. He should ask what math agrees with the observation.

Comment: @dmckee I'll compromise; you can give proof of a physical occurrence, given a suitable set of axioms. These axioms do have to come from experiment, thoughtful or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [Wheeler's delayed choice experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%27s_delayed_choice_experiment), which "is actually several thought experiments in quantum physics, proposed by John Archibald Wheeler [...] These experiments are attempts to decide whether light somehow "senses" the experimental apparatus in the double-slit experiment it will travel through and adjusts its behavior to fit by assuming the appropriate determinate state for it, or whether light remains in an indeterminate state, neither wave nor particle, until measured." **It was first proposed by Wheeler in 1978**.

This thought experiment was made real in 1999 by [Yoon-Ho Kim, Marlan Scully, et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.3977)